# How to divide all values in nested list by 255?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list my_list:

```py
[
    [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
    [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
    [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
    [95, 202, 190, 1.0]
]
```

I want to divide all values in it by 255. How could I get this new nested sublist with values divided by 255?

Comment: Suggest using list comprehension.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension

```
ll = [[255, 102, 0, 1.0],
  [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
  [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
  [95, 202, 190, 1.0]]
ll = [[x/255 for x in l] for l in ll]
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to do it, but I'd do it like this as a quick 'n dirty

```
>>> ll = [[255, 102, 0, 1.0],
...   [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
...   [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
...   [95, 202, 190, 1.0]]
>>> res = []
>>> for x in ll:
...   inner = []
...   for z in x:
...     inner.append(z/255)
...   res.append(inner)
>>> pprint(res)
[[1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
 [1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
 [1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
 [0.37254901960784315,
  0.792156862745098,
  0.7450980392156863,
  0.00392156862745098]]
```

This works only when you have only 1 level of nested lists. If you need to support deeper structure, I'd try to solve this with recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best Idea is using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

data = [[255, 102, 0, 1.0],
        [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
        [255, 102, 0, 1.0],
        [95, 202, 190, 1.0]]

out = list(np.divide(data, 255)) 
print(out)
```

Output

```
[[1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
[1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
[1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
[0.37254901960784315, 0.792156862745098, 0.7450980392156863, 0.00392156862745098]]
```

Comment: it will bring array([[1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
[1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
[1.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.00392156862745098],
[0.37254901960784315, 0.792156862745098, 0.7450980392156863, 0.00392156862745098]])

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: i need to get nested list, not array. same format as input data

Comment: please add the example of what you want in your question

Comment: Simply convert it back to a `list` with `out = list(np.divide(data, 255))`

Comment: Nice, thanks I did it @AnsFourtyTwo